# radgrid enable user to insert html into column

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Is it possible in edit mode of my radgrid to enable user to insert html code. It would be great if I can use wysiwig editor to do that.

Thank You very much for any help, example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can put RadEditor in template column, you have example in demos :

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/columntypes/defaultcs.aspx

and KB article:

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/grid/using-radeditor-as-editor-in-template-column-of-radgrid.aspx